# HTML Screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having problem with pixels on web page. I have cover image on body and button on it. When page does resize, button is moving too. I want to stay button there where I put it even when screen changes. I'm trying to port website on mobile devices too, that's why I have that problem. P.S I'm new to web programming.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
        <title>test page.</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background:url("test.jpg");
                background-size: cover;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
            }
            #mybutton {
                position: absolute;
                right:800px;
                top:300px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="mybutton" onClick="javascript:alert('clicked!');">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you put a fiddle of this ?

Comment: Do you want the button relative to the background image?

Comment: here's fiddle if I did it correctly.
@Liam, yes, I want it to be relative in that position where it is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WDHTZ/

Comment: that js fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: it is working... just the right is too much. Change the right of button to 300px

Comment: I still dont get what you want... do you want your button to stay where it is positioned... even after scrolling or screen resize??

Comment: Nope, to follow it to picture location, I've posted simple explanation below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so your getting yourself confused here I believe. So `position: absolute;` says:

> position this element relative to the top right hand corner of the
>   browser window

so if the browser window resizes so your position changes. the approach I believe you should actually take is to constrain the size of your "canvas". I.e. this is how big the background image is so I'm going to keep my "canvas" this size, i.e.

http://jsfiddle.net/bLUhL/1/

if you resize the screen in this fiddle you'll see the button stay in the same position relative to the "canvas" and this is always in the centre.

You can then position the button using margins:

```
input
{
 margin-left:200px;
    margin-right:300px;
}
```

Comment: maybe I asked wrong? imagine picture on background where is earth or something, and at let's say Europe's location, I'm adding button, which follows it's position even when browser resizes.

Comment: Yes, the above will do that. Replace the blue color with your image and put the button over Europe using the margins

Answer (score 0):

make css property position as fixed of mybutton.

```
         #mybutton {
            position: fixed;
            right:800px;
            top:300px;
        }
```

Comment: @user2399415 dont know what you want. button can not go out of the browser. it has to be within the DOM/browser. so by resizing , it has to move .

Answer (score 0):

try tweaking this to your needs:

```
#mybutton {
    position: fixed;
    right: 150px;
    top: 49%;
    display: block;
}
```

or, in other words, use position:fixed

Comment: wow, 4 answers in less of 2 mins...that was easy :))
if you wish you can use pixels instead of percentage for top property.

Comment: also changing background-size properties to auto or contain could help, not sure to have fully understood what you're trying to do, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

try this dude..position fixed is the best way. If you use absolute button will be go up when u scroll the page.. and

> right:0; top:0;

will be help your button to keep top right..

```
 #mybutton {
            position: fixed;
            right:0;
            top:0;
            width:100px;//what u want
            height:30px;//what u want
        }
```

if you want some margin from top and right use this

> right:100px;//what u want
>
> top:100px;//what u want

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `left` instead of `right`.

The absolute element will be positioned against first parent whose position is relative.

So you can have a button whose position is absolute. And on top it, there will be a div whose position will be relative. Then you can give position to your button, relative/against that div.

Which will be fixed, despite of screen size.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WDHTZ/2/)

Comment: That image should be background cover btw.